# Device Name DNS Test

Tags: perl, dns

I am trying to write a Perl script that checks if the device's name exists in DNS and if it doesn't, it prints the device's name. Currently, this is how I do that:

```
my $host_result = `host $device`;
my @host_result = split(/ /, $host_result);
my $dns = $host_result[0];

# host normally puts out something like this if there is an error:
# Host blah not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
# So I check to see if the first word is 'Host'
if ($dns eq "Host") {
    print $device;
}
```

As you can see, I use the system's [`host`](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_host.htm) command to do this. More specifically, I check to see if `host` can find the device's name or not.

I know that this is not the purpose of `host` and I don't want to be using system calls unless I really have to, so I was hoping someone could point me towards a Perl module that allows me to check these device names against DNS. I'm guessing [Net::DNS](http://search.cpan.org/~nlnetlabs/Net-DNS-0.72/lib/Net/DNS.pm), but what specifically inside Net::DNS should I use to accomplish this?

I Googled around, but I'm having a hard time finding anything because I don't know what to look for (is it a DNS query? or DNS resolution?), because I only have a basic understanding of DNS and the terminology related to it.

Also, I'm passing in a lot of device names, so any tips on how to speed up the check are welcome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not very knowledgeable about DNS either, but I think this would be a rough equivalent to the `host` approach using [Net::DNS::Resolver](http://search.cpan.org/~nlnetlabs/Net-DNS-0.72/lib/Net/DNS/Resolver.pm):

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Net::DNS::Resolver;

my $device = shift;
my $res = Net::DNS::Resolver->new;
say $device unless $res->search($device); # Returns undef if not found
```

In terms of speed, I did a simple benchmark and [Net::DNS::Resolver](http://search.cpan.org/~nlnetlabs/Net-DNS-0.72/lib/Net/DNS/Resolver.pm) is way faster than `system("host $device")` if you reuse the same Resolver object for each query. Here are my timing results when the host is not in DNS:

```
          Rate   system Net::DNS
system   233/s       --     -60%
Net::DNS 578/s     148%       --
```

There's an even bigger difference when the host *is* in DNS:

```
          Rate   system Net::DNS
system   232/s       --     -69%
Net::DNS 758/s     227%       --
```

Here is the code I used for the benchmark:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Benchmark qw(cmpthese);
use Net::DNS::Resolver;

our $device = shift;
our $res = Net::DNS::Resolver->new;

cmpthese(1000, {
    system     => sub { system("host $device > /dev/null 2>&1"); },
    'Net::DNS' => sub { $res->search($device); }
});
```

---

I also see that [Net::DNS::Resolver](http://search.cpan.org/~nlnetlabs/Net-DNS-0.72/lib/Net/DNS/Resolver.pm) has a function to [run a query in the background](http://search.cpan.org/~nlnetlabs/Net-DNS-0.72/lib/Net/DNS/Resolver.pm#bgsend) and return immediately. If speed is really an issue, you could try sending your queries like this and forking a new process to check the results as soon as they're ready. Alternatively, you could just fork a process for each call to the normal foreground `search()` function. Of course, depending on the number of hosts you're checking, be aware that you could run into memory or process limits with this approach.

Comment: Great! I had used it before and it wasn't working. However, your use of `say` made me realize that I should probably `chomp` my strings before checking them and now it works!